# How to enable domain name search in my website

Tags: wordpress, domain-name

I'm designing a website for domain registration and hosting company using wordpress...I have designed the website and added the plugin for domain name search...now my question is

1) Is that plugin is enough to search and find available domain names globally ?

or

I need pay for someone like go daddy or name cheap or who is to find out the available domain name in my website ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many domain name registries. For example .com TLD is distributed by Verisign whereas a .uk TLD is distributed by Nominet (this will include domain extensions like .co.uk or .org.uk etc...)

So the question is are you directly talking to the domain registries or are you resellers of other brands. For example you could be a reseller of Go Daddy or 101domains or 123-reg. Which basically means (as an example) you will talk to their API for a domain name availability and as long as they support that domain extension, they will come back to you on whether it is available or not.

Your question is too general to be answered specifically.

Comment: They are going to be like Reseller of server...so they need to get the API for name search from that particular concern right ?

Comment: Your domain availability plugin can do that. You just have to check what the plug-in is actually using to do its domain lookup and what domain extensions it supports to be sure.

Comment: If I was helpful to you would you mind upvoting please